# if statement in where clause mysql syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, where-clause

I am trying to use if condition in MySQL. I am getting a syntax error. I tried looking at a lot of other Stack Overflow discussions but couldn't figure it out. Can anyone please help me?

This is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
$branch = $_POST['branch'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM table
WHERE branch='$branch' and testcase like 
IF(isset(_$POST['testcase']),'$_POST['testcase']','1=1')";
....
}
```

I want to do an and operation in `WHERE` between `branch='$branch'` and `testcase` depending on weather it is selected or not in my form. If it is selected, I want to do an and operation between branch and the value of `testcase`. If not, I just want to filter out results on `$branch` value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to have a dynamic query based on the whether the `testcase` value is set or not?

If that is the case you can try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
$branch = $_POST['branch'];
$testcase = "";

 if (isset($_POST['testcase'])) {
    $testcase = "and testcase like '" . $_POST['testcase'] . "'";
 }

 $query = "SELECT * FROM table
 WHERE branch='$branch' $testcase";
```

This way if the testcase value is set it will set `$testcase` to the `and testcase like` portion of the query. If it is not set then it will be an empty string which will leave the `$query` with only the `$branch` value.

Comment: worked like a charm. thank you so much. Made my day.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help.

Comment: hey Deepak, sorry you'll need to explain a bit more. How do you want the query to look with the multiple values of `testcase`? The query might not work right if you simply add on more parameters for `testcase`.

Comment: I figured out the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Isset is not a mysql command, it is a php command. You need to build your variable first.

```
$bleach = false

IF(isset($_POST['testcase'])
{
$bleach = $_POST['testcase']
}
Else 
{
$bleach=1
}
```

Then pass $bleach into your query

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE branch='$branch' and testcase='$testcase'"; if this is the query, then I'm not able to submit my form until I select both. I just want to filter the results out even if only the branch value is set. Can you help me out here?

Comment: See the answer above. See how he/she is building the sql statement based on if testcase is set?  If it is not set, your query ends. If it is set, append the query.

Comment: yep. Just figured it out now. Thanks for the help.